# Using the Twitter API, how do you get the total number of times a hashtag has been used in the past?

Tags: twitter

Let's say people have used the hashtag #YOLOplanking 4701 times from the birth of Twitter to 2018. How do you get that 4701 number, without having to become an omniscient deity?

Comment: Seems this isn't possible without a third-party service: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-obtain-the-number-of-times-a-particular-hashtag-has-been-used-using-the-Twitter-API

Comment: That third-party service would be using the Twitter API during the query though, wouldn't it?

Comment: It would be impossible for you to query the full history of a popular hashtag due to their rate limits. Most of those services have likely purchased historical data from Twitter.

Comment: The only way I'm aware of would be to use Twitter's (commercial) enterprise full archive search product - it provides a count endpoint which would enable you to fetch counts over time. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview/enterprise - with the standard API you are limited to a 7 day search window.